# Не может найти класс org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl

Tags: java, java-ee, jersey, jax-rs

При запросе и попытке на валидацию, программа печатает "In the constraint if else" после чего выскакивает в логе ошибка о нехватки класса!

В инете нашол инфу о том что надо иметь зависимость Jersey-Common! 
После чего скачал с Maven репозитория но получаю туже ошибку!

1. Для чего нужен данный класс ?
2. Какая зависимость отвечает за данный класс ?

   > > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
   > >         at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)
   > >         at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)

Из логов видно что идёт обрашение к findDelegate() а после чего возникает ошибка..

Какие могут быть причины не нахождения данного класса ?

```
     public class ClientDataValidation {

     public Response validator(User user){


    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraints = validator.validate(user);

    if(!(constraints.isEmpty())){

        System.out.print("In the constraint if else");

        String [] errors = new String[constraints.size()]; int constraintCounter = 0;

        for (ConstraintViolation<User> constraint:constraints) {

            String errorMessage = constraint.getMessage();
            errors[constraintCounter] = errorMessage;
            constraintCounter++;
        }

        constraintCounter = 0;
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity(errors);
        Response resposne = responseBuilder.build();  errors = null; 
        return  resposne;
    }


    return  Response.ok().build();
      }
    }


<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

> > at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
> >         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
> >         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
> >         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
> >         at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:115)
> >         at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
> >         at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
> >         ... 29 more
> >
> > > 03-Oct-2016 01:43:55.277 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [registrationServlet] in context with path [/CouponProject] threw exception
> > >        java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:848)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:590)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:601)
> > >           at coupon.validation.ClientDataValidation.validator(ClientDataValidation.java:36)
> > >           at coupon.registration.Register.doPost(Register.java:33)
> > >           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
> > >           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> > >           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
> > >           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
> > >           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
> > >           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
> > >           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
> > >           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> > >           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> > >           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> > >           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> > >       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
> > >           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
> > >           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> > >           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:115)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
> > >           at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
> > >           ... 29 more

Из моего проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это у Вас RESTFull? Каким образом он разворачивается? Прописан в web.xml, или через Application?

Comment: Стиль REST, использую обыные сервлеты (doGet , doPost). Descriptor  с аннотациями. Разворачивается очень просто , IDEA всё делает сама надо немного настроек, создаёт war exploded etc ...

Comment: А сервер приложений какой? Там точно jersey?

Comment: Использую Maven + Tomcat 8. Насчёт зависимостей всё есть, Maven сам скачивает всё что надо, Jersey только сам Resposne, ResponseBuilder классы, через которые создавался экземпляр RuntimeDelegate, который и не находился при создании. Могу скинуть исходники самого StackTrace.. там видно что при попытке создать экземпляр RuntimeDelegate всё валится.

Comment: Добрый день.Удалось как-нибудь решить проблему? сейчас столкнулся с подобной.